# Export Highcharts and its data into Excel

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am still not getting to server side export highchart please help me.I have downloaded     highchart in that i already have exporting server folder.

In that,i have php batik phantomJS and one exportController.pls help

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this solution about exporting to csv http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2495153-export-chart-data-to-csv-excel-and-more-via-dat